# Check bit value at particular position in a binary with C language

Tags: c, gcc, binary

I don't know why, I tried all the implementations I've found here in stack, but every of them have this strange behaviour.

My aim is: given a decimal, change it to binary and retrieve a bit at given position value.

Let's say I got this binary, which is decimal 255:

```
11111111
```

Well using this:

```
#define CHECK_BIT(var,pos) ((var) & (1<<(pos)))//other test
#define NCHECK_BIT(int, pos) (!! int  & (1 << pos))
unsigned char* REG_SW ;

//from int to binary
unsigned int int_to_int(unsigned int k) {
    return (k == 0 || k == 1 ? k : ((k % 2) + 10 * int_to_int(k / 2)));
}

int checkBitPosition(){ 
    REG_SW = (unsigned char*) 0x300111;
    return NCHECK_BIT(int_to_int(REG_SW [0]),6)==false?1:0 ;
}
```

it returns me true if the bit is 0 at sixth but also second (and some others..actually!!) so the results are impredictable... I didn't get the logic behind that gives me the result.
I assume that the int to binary translator works well, 'cause I'm printing that and it's always the correct binary taken from the int I give.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, why -1, what did i do?

Comment: Posting some examples of input and expected output would help clear up some confusing aspects of this post.

Comment: Remove the `int_to_int` function. It serves no purpose at all. A number is just a number. It makes no sense to convert "int to binary" as you put it. And then why are you reading memory at hard coded addresses? What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting a number into its binary format first and then you are checking that binary format with your macros. This is wrong, since your macros will check for the position of the bit in the resulting number (not your original number) i.e,

first your number = `10` and binary format is `1010`
now to check the bits you have to pass `10` as argument for your macros and not `1010`

if you pass the binary representation `1010` to the macro then binary representation of the number `1010` will be checked for `pos` and not for 10.

Comment: Actually, OP is not converting a number into "a binary format," they are converting one number into a completely different number that, *when displayed as a decimal value*, happens to consist of a series of 1 and 0 digits in the same sequence as the bit values in the original number.  It is now a completely different number, not a "binary representation."  As was pointed out in another comment, *a number is just a number."  In other words, 10 != 2, 11 != 3, etc.